# Is this the correct way to set up an onkeypress listener in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to setup an `onkeypress` listener in an AngularJS application to be able to catch all keypresses.

Questions:

- Is this the correct way to achieve this is using AngularJS?
- Can the code be improved in any way to make it more in line with AngularJS best practices?

This is the HTML code I'm using:

```
<html ng-app="moduleName">
  <body ng-controller="ControllerName" ng-keypress="keyPress($event)">
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the JavaScript code:

```
var app = angular.module("moduleName", []);
var ControllerName = function($scope) {
    $scope.keyPress = function($event) {
        // Logic goes here.
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Angular Application have multiple controllers, hence, you may want to:-

1. Set keyPress method to rootscope on app initialization (as it seems you want this method to get called from keypress anywhere in application.

   ```
   app.config(['$routeProvider', '$rootScope',
     function ($routeProvider, $rootScope) {
       $routeProvider.when('/Sample', {
           templateUrl: 'views/Sample.html',
           controller: 'sampleController'
       });

       $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/app' });
       $rootScope.keypress = function($event) {
           /* some code goes here */
       };
   }]);
   ```
2. You can also use directive for same purpose, which look like more appropriate way of handling this

   ```
   app.directive('listenToKeypress', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                elem.bind('keypress', function(e) {
                    /* do something here */
                });
        }
      };
   });
   ```

and html can be :-

```
<html ng-app="moduleName">
  <body ng-controller="ControllerName" listen-to-keypress>
  </body>
</html>
```